# Which C# concurrent construct to use for a simple waitAll and signalAll scenario.

Tags: c#, concurrency

In my C# program, a shared data cache is accessed by threads. Periodically this data cache needs to be updated and I want all the accessing threads to wait until the update completes. When the data cache is updated. I want all the threads to be signaled and resume the access. I am not sure what .NET concurrent construct to use for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more search I found the answer myself, in case you need it:

**ReaderWriterLock Class**
Defines a lock that supports single writers and multiple readers.

Comment: You should the improved version of that: `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple lock would do the trick:

```
class RestrictedCache
{
    private Cache cache = //...;
    private object _lock = new{};
    public object Get(string key)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            return cache[key];
        }
    }
    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            cache[key]=value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put lock on the Get(). At anytime there can be only one reader. That's not what I want.

Comment: @sean717 have you benchmarked that doing only one reader slows your program down noticeably?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, No. But I thought there should be some construct let me to do something like "ManualResetEvent.SetAll()"

Comment: You'd probably benefit from getting to grips with [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then.